# Function name must be a string. Can't display data from database using rows

Tags: php, database, function

This is my event coding. I want it to display the Event Properties in my system. The error display is

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   D:\XAMPP\htdocs\system\bulletin.php

What does it means by function name must be a string ?
Where is the error ? Which line should I change ?

```
<th scope="col"><center><strong>Event ID</strong></center></th>
<th scope="col"><center><strong>Event</strong></center></th>
<th scope="col"><center><strong>Description of the Event</strong></center></th>

<?php
require 'database.php';

$qry = "SELECT * FROM bulletin ORDER BY event_id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($qry) OR die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result())){
$event_id = $row['event_id'];
$event = $row['event'];
$venue = $row['venue'];
$daydropdown_start = $row['day1'];
$monthdropdown_start = $row['month1'];
$yeardropdown_start = $row['year1'];
}


<td><? echo $row['event_id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['event']; ?></td>
<td><br>Venue:<?php echo $row['venue']; ?></br>
<br>  Date: <?php echo $row['day1'] / $row['month1'] / $row['year1']; ?> </br></td>
```

Comment: The error show at the line "while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result()))"

Comment: `$result` is not a function...remove `()`...and `mysql` extension is deprecated...not safe to use it

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your error is in this line `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result())){`

`$result` isn't a function, but a variable. Change it to

`while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){`, and you should be good

Comment: Okay. I've removed the () form the $result as you said. There is no more error displayed but now none of my database is display. Its empty. Why is it so ?

Comment: could be something with the database? Also, put your echo statements inside the while loop

Comment: database is completely fine. I've tested it. echo statements inside while loops ? Where at ? Could you show me the example ?